# Which keyboard keys are absent on most keyboards but are supported by Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard

What are keys that Windows supports but are not often on any keyboard, like the <kbd>F13</kbd>-<kbd>F24</kbd> keys – or is that all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question does not have exact answer because you write "not often on any keyboard" which sounds vague. On the other hand, I understand the merit of the question.

I was examining this topic some time ago and based on list of [Keyboard scan codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) and its programmatic testing I compiled the following

**List of rarely present keys:**

- <kbd>F13</kbd>–<kbd>F24</kbd>
- <kbd>Clear</kbd>
- <kbd>PA1</kbd>
- <kbd>Select</kbd>
- <kbd>Print</kbd>
- <kbd>Execute</kbd>
- <kbd>Attn</kbd>
- <kbd>CrSel</kbd>
- <kbd>ExSel</kbd>
- <kbd>Erase EOF</kbd>
- <kbd>Help</kbd>

Many of these are legacy keys from computer systems of the past. Their meaning can be sometimes found (example: [PA1 key](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB27U_6.4.0/com.ibm.zvm.v640.dmsb3/dmsb3232.htm)), sometimes not easily.

<kbd>Clear</kbd> and <kbd>Help</kbd> may be still in use on Apple keyboards.